# MDM Wiping Data when device lost scenario

Tags: iphone, mdm, payload, data-security

How does the 'wipeout data' command/payload executes on a lost device and powered off.

I know the 'Security Info' command when fired on a powered off or locked device, the status comes as 'Notnow' and the command is queued up. The queued command is executed immediately after the device is powered on and/or unlocked.

Does the 'wipe data' command executes the same way as 'Security Info'?

Also I think 'wipe data' must also execute even if the device is locked.. Right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MDM protocol document, the device will receive the MDM push when it is turned back on. It will then perform the usual 'phone home' to the server.

A device will never respond with 'NotNow' if it is powered off because, well, it's powered off! The MDM push will not be received by the device until it is powered back on.

If by 'executes in the same way', it's an XML block delivered from the server and is one of the commands that will execute when the device is locked.